# How to skip rows with no entry in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using code to generate emails from an Excel sheet.

Example Spreadsheet
[image]

The code generates an email for each row, with the recipient in Column C. (It pulls the date from Column D into the body of the email and attaches the file linked in Column E if there is one.)

The code works, but it generates an email when there is no email address in Column C.
I want to skip rows with no email address in Column C.

Comment: You're already doing something similar with `If Cells(rowIndex, 11) <> "" Then` - just do the same thing with `If Len(sourceWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, "C").Value)>0` so you only create a mailitem when there's a *to* address.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried adding the If statement but I am still having an issue. When I add the If statement before "W MItem" I get an error on "Next rowIndex". When I add the If statement before ".To", it still generates the email when email address is blank and messes up the attachments. Can you provide any additional insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Sub CreateEmails()

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim MItem As Object, sTo As String, rw As Range
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For rowIndex = 2 To wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rw = wsSrc.Rows(rowIndex) 'the row we're on...
        sTo = rw.Columns("C").value
        If Len(sTo) > 0 Then           '<<< need to create a mail?
            With OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
                .To = sTo
                .Subject = "Subject here"
                .CC = "myemail@email.com"
                .Attachments.Add "attachment link here"
        
                If rw.Columns("K").value <> "" Then .Attachments.Add rw.Columns("E").value
                 'adds a second attachment if there is a link in column E
                .htmlBody = "<p><font face = ""Calibri(Body)"" font size=""3"" color=""black"">Good afternoon, </p>" & _
                    "<p><font face = ""Calibri(Body)"" font size=""3"" color=""black"">" & _
                    "<strong>Please review the attached and return by " & Cells(rowIndex, 4) & ".</strong>  </p>" & _
                    "<p><font face = ""Calibri(Body)"" font size=""3"" color=""black"">" & _
                    "Please reach out to me if you have any questions. </p>" & .htmlBody
        
                .display 'Change to .send to send automatically
            End With
        End If 'have To address
    Next rowIndex
End Sub
```